# Using camelCased columns in a postgresql where clause

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with camelCased column names (which I now deeply regret). If I use double quotation marks around the column names as part of the `SELECT` clause, they work fine, e.g. `SELECT "myCamelCasedColumn" FROM the_table;`. If, however, I try doing the same in the `WHERE` clause, then I get an error.

For example, `SELECT * FROM the_table WHERE "myCamelCasedColumn" = "hello";` gives me the error `column "hello" does not exist`.

How can I get around this? If I don't surround the column in double quotation marks then it will just complain that `column mycamelcasedcolumn does not exist`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL string literals are enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes.

```
SELECT * 
FROM the_table 
WHERE "myCamelCasedColumn" = 'hello';
```

See the manual for details: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

The manual also explains why `"myCamelCasedColumn"` is something different in SQL than `myCamelCasedColumn`

---

In general you should stay away from quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. If you never use double quotes everything is a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use double quote for strin literal `"hello"`. Should be `'hello'`. Double quotes is reserved for identifiers.